# Get the joint probability function from the distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the probability distribution function defined as
$$
f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
      2, & 0 < x < y < 1 \\
      0, & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$

And I need to find the joint distribution function of the Random Pair. I'm very confused about this, but my textbook doesn't explain it very well (it doesn't explain it at all - just provide formulas). I'm not able to understand how did they get to the solution, which is:

$$
F_{X, Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x < 0 \text{ or } y < 0 \\
      2x(y-\frac{x}{2}) & 0 < x < y < 1 \\
      2x(1-\frac{x}{2}) & 0 < x < 1, y > 1 \\
      y^2 & 0 < y < x < 1 \text{ or } 0 < y < 1 < x \\
      1 & x > 1, y > 1 
   \end{cases}$$

First of all, if the probability distribution function is only defined for $0 < x < y < 1$ why is there conditions like $y > 1$ and $x > 1$ and $0 < y < x < 1$ for the joint probability distribution? Should I just care about the first two?

For $0 < x < y < 1$ I tried:

$$\int_0^x\int_x^yf_{X, Y}(u, v)dvdu = 2\int_0^x(y-x)du = 2x(y-x)$$

Which is not the same (I'm maybe making some mistake on the second integral?).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> For $0 < x < y < 1$ I tried:
>
> $$\int_0^x\int_x^yf_{X, Y}(u, v)dvdu = 2\int_0^x(y-x)du = 2x(y-x)$$

No, since $u,v$ are the bound variables, and $x,y$ are constant constraints, you want to integrate over the domain: $$\{\langle u, v\rangle:0<u<v<1, u<x, v<y\}$$

So, for the part where $0<x<y<1$ you need:

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}\int_{u}^{y} 2\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u&:&0<x<y<1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\end{cases}$$